# Chrome and chromium refuse to run on ubuntu 20

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

When starting I got message "Fatal process out of memory: Failed to reserve memory for new V8 IsolateFatal process out of memory: Failed to reserve memory for new V8 Iso"

Applies to chromium and google-chrome after version 79. Version 79 still runs fine, but I had to downgrade manually to get a working version...

Any idea what I can do ? By the way, this is not a RAM problem:

free -h
total       utilisé      libre     partagé tamp/cache   disponible
Mem:           22Gi       4,1Gi        12Gi       597Mi       6,4Gi        17Gi
Partition d'échange:        23Gi          0B        23Gi

Comment: Please clarify your release. The closest is Ubuntu Core 20 as specialist *snap* based releases use the *yy* format, unlike *yy.mm* used by server & desktops releases, but your question (talk about browsers) seem to be more a standard *yy.mm* release not a *yy* release.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, however issue is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i will respond my own question. I found out that the problem was caused by a setting in /etc/security/limits.conf . I had limited the max memory to 8GB for my user ! It seems that chrome and chromium cannot run with less than 8GB ?? Which seems weird to me.... is this a "feature" or a "bug" in chromium ?

Comment: I had similar problem. I disable some access that I do not understand why Chromium has to have and it did not start.